# Fractional derivative via Continuous Functional Calculus

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, differential-operators, pseudo-differential-operators

If we study C* algebras, at one point or another we are exposed to the idea of the Continuous functional Calculus, i.e. if $\mathcal{Y}$ is a unital C* algebra, $\xi \in \mathcal{Y}$ is normal, that is $\xi^*\xi = \xi\xi^*$, then we can make sense of the expression $f(\xi)$, where $f \in \mathcal{C}(\sigma(\xi))$ (= all complex valued, continuous functions on the spectrum $\sigma(\xi)$ of $\xi$). I just recently stumbled upon a video about fractional derivatives, and shortly after I read the corresponding wikipedia article (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_calculus). In the wikipedia article it is mentioned that one can use the continuous functional calculus in order to give precise meaning to $D^\alpha$, where $D$ is a differentiation operator and $\alpha >0$. As the article points to pseudo-differential operators, and I unfortunately don't have much of a clue of that, I didn't quite seem to find an explanation of how to define $D^\alpha$ in that way. So my question is as follows:

> Which C* algebra $\mathcal{Y}$ are we considering so that $D \in \mathcal{Y}$ and $D$ is normal with respect to the involution on $\mathcal{Y}$, so that we may properly define $D^\alpha$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know where the Wikipedia article is coming from, but I don't think what you want to do can be done.

First, I'm not aware of a context where a differential operator is bounded as an operator on a Hilbert space. So I don't see how you would put a differential operator inside a C$^*$-algebra.

Second, differential operators are not positive, so doing functional calculus with a function that is only defined for positive values (as are fractional powers) is no-go.

Comment: True, I was thinking the same. I will wait some time though, before I accept your answer. Maybe someone else can provide a reference for the claim made in Wikipedia. Isn't there a continuous functional Calculus for unbounded Operators?

Comment: There's even Borel functional calculus for normal operators. The Spectral Theorem holds basically the same. But no C$^*$-algebra will be involved.

Comment: Hm I see. I am guessing the unbounded version would also not be suitable right?

Comment: Probably. I guess it depends on the context. To use the Spectral Theorem you would need $D$ to be densely defined (mostly not an issue), closed, and $D^*D=DD^*$.  Then you would need to make sure that your fractional power is defined as a function on $\sigma(D)$, although this is probably not an issue.

Comment: Is the unbounded version of the spectral theorem for normal operators proved or derived by utilizing the spectral theorem for normal elements in a C* algebra?

Comment: I would have to check. But the spectral theorem does not work in C$^*$-algebras in general. The Borel functional calculus requires a von Neumann algebra.

Comment: I see! Thanks for your help and time, I will look into that some more :)